# Why WordPress HTML editor remove <p> tag and <br>? Can we stop this?

Tags: php, wordpress, paragraph, html-editor

I need to make some static pages in WordPress I like to make it through HTML editor as I need to change text regularly. My page layout is not looking good as the HTML editor removing `<p>` and `<br>` tags.

For example if I am entering below HTML in editor through 'text' mode.

```
<p>Some Text</P>
<a>google.com</a>
```

click on 'Visual' tab and again switch to 'text' mode, then the HTML will change like below.

```
Some Text
<a>google.com</a>
```

I have installed "Tinymce-advanced" and configured setting to stop removing `<p>` tag and `<br/>` tag. Then it stop removing `<p>` tag but then the editor start adding `<p>` tags randomly for example then above HTML code will be looking like below.

```
<p>Some Text</p>
<p><a>google.com</a></p>
```

Kindly share your suggestions

Comment: Maybe if you remove the autocorrect option? `/wp-admin/options-writing.php`

Comment: here is my observation,
it will replace <span >, 
font- this is replaced with span with inline style, 
frame and frameset is replaced with &nbsp;
optgroup and option  - select box with two optgroups separated into two select box